# Python argparse - Detect if list argument is passed without anything afterwards

Tags: python, list, argparse

Let's say the user types:

`./args.py --create --mem 5`

and my parser looks like this:

`parser.add_argument('--create', nargs='*', default=None)`

Normally `--create` takes a list with `nargs='*'`, however in this case the user passed nothing.

What I would like to happen is that `--create` is set to the default value when invoked, instead I get `[]`

Question: Is there anyway to detect if `--create` shows up in the command line arguments without anything after it?

Comment: `create` is set to a list of the strings that follow.  WIth '*', that list may be empty, `[]`.

Comment: The trick is that `create = default` when not passed and `create = []` when passed without anything following. I was expecting the other way around.

Comment: So now my code is looking for `[]` instead of the default value.

Comment: Default for a `positional` with `nargs='*' is extra tricky, since 'nothing' satisfies its requirements..  It is always seen, even when there aren't any strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple code snippet:

```py
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--create', nargs='*', default=None)
options = parser.parse_args()
print(options)
```

Here are a few interactions:

```
$ ./args.py 
Namespace(create=None)

$ ./args.py --create
Namespace(create=[])

$ ./args.py --create one
Namespace(create=['one'])

$ ./args.py --create one two
Namespace(create=['one', 'two'])
```

As you can see, if the user does not add the `--create` flag, it is `None`. If the user use `--create` flag with nothing, you get an empty list.